# Why does "$ sudo echo 'yo' " work even though echo is a shell built in function?

Tags: shell, sudo, echo

I understand that

```
sudo cd /directory
```

will return:

```
sudo: cd: command not found
```

because cd is a shell builtin and not a binary. But then, why does

```
sudo echo 'this is a test'
```

works fine?

What is really going on here? How does `sudo` find the command `echo` if it's not a shell?

Comment: `sudo cd /directory` works fine here. Check that `which cd` is in your root user's `$PATH`.

Comment: To make matters worse, System IV actually had a /usr/bin/cd which did not change directory in the shell.

Answer (score 19):

The reason is simple, `cd` is a shell builtin (and shell function in some shells), while `echo` is both a binary and a shell builtin:

```
$ type -a cd  
cd is a shell builtin
$ type -a echo 
echo is a shell builtin
echo is /bin/echo
```

`sudo` can't handle shell builtins, but can handle binaries in the `$PATH`. When you use `sudo echo`, `/bin/echo` is found in the `$PATH`, so it uses that, meanwhile `sudo cd` can't find `cd` in the `$PATH` hence it fails.

Answer (score 4):

running

```
 which echo
```

gives

```
 /bin/echo
```

`echo` is a plain program, and `sudo` can "find" it.

On a side note, there must be some option in `sudoers(5)`

Answer (score 3):

The issue is more for `sudo cd` to fail on your OS than `sudo echo` to succeed.

`sudo cd /directory` is quite a legitimate method to check if a given user, likely `root` here, is allowed to `cd` to some directory. That is the reason why all Posix compliant OSes **do** provide an executable version of `cd`.

So the answer to you question is `sudo echo yo` works by design because `echo` is provided by both a shell alias and an executable command but `sudo cd /directory` does not because your OS, likely Gnu/Linux based, is breaking [the Posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_06) in this specific case.

A simple workaround for your system would be to run `sudo sh -c "cd /directory"`

Comment: Down voters should think twice ... or at least leave a comment.

Comment: I didn't vote, but it occurs to me that this doesn't answer the question. ***You*** should leave a comment; i.e., the above should be a comment on the question.

Comment: @jlliagre your assertion is wrong. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/cd.html "Since cd affects the current shell execution environment, it is always provided as a shell regular built-in."

Comment: @Patrick My assertion is right. Read closely the last paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_06

Comment: @G-Man Thanks for commenting. Answer updated to provide an answer, more explanations and a workaround.